# Receiving 403 FORBIDDEN when sending request with parameters from WIZnet W5500 to a server

Tags: http, request, httprequest, http-status-code-403

I'm using the W5500 Ethernet Chip to connect to a server as a client. When I send a request like that:

GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.siblette.de\r\n\r\n

the server returns 200 OK.

But as soon as I add parameters e.g.:

GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [www.siblette.de?a=1\r\n\r\n](http://www.siblette.de?a=1%5Cr%5Cn%5Cr%5Cn)

The server returns 403 FORBIDDEN.

When I just type [www.siblette.de?a=1](http://www.siblette.de?a=1) into my google chrome browser the page opens without error. So I think the problem is the setup of the GET request message string. Maybe there is something missing inside the GET request what the server needs for permission.

Can anybody help me?

And: does anybody know where I can find some information about the general setup of requests?

Greetings,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

I used Wireshark to check how a request message is setup correctly. Listening to the server IP and typing `"siblette.de/?a=1"` into the webbrowser. Correct is:

```
GET /?a=1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.siblette.de\r\n\r\n
```